# How can I encrypt data with a password, but allow said password to be reset

Tags: encryption

I'm asking at a purely abstract level (no code required).

Some data is to be stored on a web-server/database on behalf of a user. The data is encrypted using the user's password as the key, ensuring that if the server or database is compromised, it is relatively useless to the attacker.

The problem is that the standard process of resetting a user's password (sending them a link with a token) won't work, because there is no way to decrypt and re-encrypt the data without knowing the previous password.

Are there any other ways around this?

Comment: Encrypt using something else.

Comment: Something else? Like something stored in the FS/DB? That defeats the purpose of encrypting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say that you are willing to reset the password using some piece of automated authentication, then what you're really saying is that there are two passwords: the "normal" password and the "authentication" password. The solution to your problem is to encrypt the file using a random key and then encrypt the key using each of the passwords.

As a concrete example:

- User provides a password "Aw3som1"
- User also provides his high school mascot: "the Chipmunks"

Just to make it really complete, let's assume your authentication scheme is very forgiving like many are. You would accept just "chipmunks" (or "CHIPMUNKS" or maybe even "chipmunk") rather than "the Chipmunks." But whatever it is, your scheme must be deterministic. Every possible answer you will accept must resolve to the same hash. In this case, I'm going to assume that you lowercase the security answer, remove articles, and reduce to singular if it's plural. Then you prepend the class of question. So your secondary password is something like "mascot:chipmunk".

You now make up a random 16-bytes and use that key to encrypt the data. You then use normal password-based encryption techniques (e.g. PBKDF2) to encrypt the key with each of your passwords above. Then you throw away the key and the passwords.

When you need to do a reset, decrypt the real key with the provided password ("mascot:chipmunk") and re-encrypt the key with the new password (and "mascot:chipmunk" again).

The one usability issue is that a password reset invalidates all the other security answers, and the user must reconfigure them all. If that's a problem, you could put all the security answers into a bundle and encrypt that using the same technique as the data. (i.e. the security answers are encrypted against all of the security answers.)

This approach of course creates two (or more) passwords that can unlock the data, and so dramatically drops brute-force search time. You should consider that when scaling things. That said, your safety margins should generally be several orders of magnitude, so even a few passwords should be workable for many situations. Remember also that the security questions live in a tiny key space, particularly things like "mascot" or "make of car" which probably only have a few dozen likely values (unless you went to my high school which had a truly bizarre mascot…) That just means that aggressively tuning PBKDF2 is even more important.

Of course the existence of any kind of password reset system is going to make targeted attacks much easier. But that's true no matter how you implement the encryption.

---

But what if there isn't even a security question? What if you'll reset the password based on an email address alone? Well, then the email address *is* the password. That's problematic in the face of a stolen database, and it's hard to fix because there is no real secret (and encryption requires a secret). But all is not completely lost. One thing you can do is to never include the actual email address in the database. Think of the email address as a password (since it is in this case). Store a hash. You can't use a random salt on it, but you could still use some single salt for the whole database.

So my email is test@example.com. You treat that as a password, salt it with "mygreatservice" and run it through PBKDF2. To login, just treat it like a password again.

An attacker, though, has to guess email addresses one at a time. That's not incredibly hard, but he can't just decrypt the entire database in one go, and he'll never get the data from emails he doesn't guess. (And you *did* choose a really easy reset mechanism.)

Comment: PBKDF2 is not encryption.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Correct. PBKDF2 is used to stretch the password into a key, not encrypt the data itself. When I say "password-based encryption techniques (e.g. PKBDF2)" I'm referring to PBE systems that generally include PBKDF2.

Comment: Super old thread, but a problem I see (with an obvious solution?) with the "email as a password" solution is that if the admin needs to send out a mass email to all users for something such as a change in TOS, this will not work.  unless there is something I'm completely missing (which is very possible) ...

Comment: @mrphuzz If you need the email for some purpose, then yes, you'll have to store the email addresses and they would make a very bad password in that case (rather than just a fairly poor password). Whether you really need to mail users who do not login (if they login, you can communicate with them at that point) is a separate issue. Not all systems require knowing users' email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to un-encrypt the password? If they have forgotten then you will have to verify them based on the fact they had access to the email account where the reset token was sent. Ideally you would include some other form of question/proof of identity on the reset page like a secret question.

Also, you're best not storing the password using reversible encryption but instead using a strong salted hash which is one way.

Comment: I don't need to decrypt the password, I would need to decrypt the data and re-encrypt it with the new password. The password would be stored as a salted hash only - not possible to decrypt.

Comment: Soory, I misunderstood what you were asking then. Could you just not use 1 master key to encrypt all data? If they can compromise your system to access the database/keys then does it matter what you used as the key? At least then you can keep the key out of a web accessible medium.